# Includegraphics load image with extension .PNG or .png

Tags: graphics, external-files

Depending how an image is produced, its file extension is either `.png` or `.PNG`. For example, if I have a file `myimage.PNG` and I place that in my document with `\includegraphics{myimage.png}` I get the error:

```
Error: File 'myimage.png' not found
```

I would like to tell `\includegraphics...` not to care whether the extension is lower case or capitalised.

Comment: Just omit the extension `:-)`

Comment: Great I didn't know that was possible, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens on file systems which distinguish between upper- and lower-case characters in file names, most notable under Linux.

One way to fix this is to rename all image files to only have lower-case extensions (try `rename '/\.PNG/.png/' *.PNG` under Linux).

Alternatively just leave the file extension and only write the file base name: `\includegraphics{myimage}`. This way a list of file extensions are then checked and the first image found is used. You can alter this list of default extensions using the macro `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions {<comma separated list>}`. By default it includes already both `.png` and `.PNG` (as well as `.jpg` and `.pdf` etc.). Note that with this way you might end up with the wrong extension if you have multiple formats of the same image, e.g. `myimage.png` and `myimage.jpg`.